# question I answered in close votes review

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618523/want-to-open-a-jquery-dialog-after-page-post-back-on-button-click-event) few hour ago. And I am reviewing some question and I got a same question for review. https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1095438.

Is it fair to vote to close question which I have answered? In situation like this how to judge a question?

Comment: Now this question is closed.

Comment: Of course it is fair! It may not get closed just because you vote so your answer can be beneficial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a bit of a personal decision really. I do often see people answering questions they ultimately vote to close. Sometimes explained as "Hey, I don't think it belongs here but at least the OP got an answer". In some way that seems like the kind thing to do.

I don't share this view. When I vote to close something, I won't answer. I might, at most, leave a comment which sort of answers the question. But most often I won't do even that. I don't feel good about gaining reputation while simultaneously saying "This does not belong here". I also feel it sends to wrong message. "Sure, your question does not belong here, but try anyway because you'll most likely get the answer". But that is my personal view and rule.

As such, whether it's fair or not really is up to you to decide.